# Error from openCV: cuda.hpp(115): error C2059: syntax error: 'constant' when building my C++ Application

Tags: c++14

I have a C++ 32-bit application, and i wanted to use opencv APIs for Image processing mainly. I have built the openCV 4.8.0 source code using cmake and Msbuild utility which has created openCV .lib files. i have only included following openCV headers files in my C++ project not even used any openCV call yet i am getting error:

```
#include "opencv2/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/videoio.hpp"
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
```

Error details:

1>    f:\elast\opencv-4.8.0\modules\flann\include\opencv2\flann\matrix.h(69): warning C4003: not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'free'
1>    f:\elast\opencv-4.8.0\modules\flann\include\opencv2\flann\matrix.h(69): error C2059: syntax error: ','
1>    f:\elast\opencv-4.8.0\modules\flann\include\opencv2\flann\matrix.h(84): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'cvflann::Matrix' being compiled
1>    f:\elast\opencv-4.8.0\modules\core\include\opencv2\core\cuda.hpp(115): error C2059: syntax error: 'constant'

I am really stuck here. any suggestion would be appreciated.

I have tried building after removing #include "opencv2/opencv.hpp", and it built successfully.